# BERT /GPT-2 and POS tags

Tags: natural-language

Can GPT-2/BERT language models be augmented with POS tags for improved style transfer?
I am asking if it is better to augment the sentences with POS tags in ordert to improve BERT and GPT 2 prediction?

Answer (score 1):

It is very unlikely that POS tags on the input would improve representation from BERT or similar models.

A linear classifier based on BERT is the state-of-the-art POS tagger, BERT already has all the information about POS tags a model can possibly have. The tags you would provide to the model as the input would be

1. Either from BERT (so it will not bring any new information); or
2. Worse than what BERT can do on its own and therefore probably useless.

Comment: Sorry , is it the same for GPT 2? do we need POS Tagging when finetuning the model on a language other than English ( for example on french text)